# Fechar duas activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Tenho duas activities que são chamadas na sequencia a seguir: A primeira é inserido um texto e assim que clicado em um botão, ele leva a uma segunda activity. 
Esta segunda Activity, ao clicar em um próximo botão, então é levada a uma terceira Activity, as duas primeiras, devem ser finalizadas e a terceira continuar na tela.

Obs: Não posso finalizar a primeira ao chamar a segunda.

É possível isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça dessa forma, quando for passar pra próxima Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Colocando essa Flag, você limpa a pilha de Acitivitys que estão acumulando.

Comment: Não sabia que tinha essa opção! Eu sempre chamava um finish pra activity que chama a outra. Bem interessante a sugestão.